# Filter dropdown list data by id in entity framework asp.net

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, drop-down-menu

I have two tables,
State:
Id_State primary key
name

city:
id_City primary key
id_State foreign key
name

I have two dropdown list, i need to load all the states in one, and when i choose one state the  city dropdown list gets loaded with the cities.

I am using entity framework and choose source in the dropdown list so it is all automatic.

Is there a way to filter the city dropdown list by the id of the state selected in the first dropdown list?

currently it loads all the states in the first dropdownlist and all the cities in the country so thats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to the `selectedindexchanged` event of drp_States:

```
string state =  drp_States.SelectedText;

List<City> filteredCities = dbcontext.Cities.Where(c=>c.StateName == state).ToList();
drp_Cities.DataSource = filteredCities;
drp_Cities.DataBind();
```

If you could provide more details about the `State` and `City` entities, I could provide a more specific solution.